# Angularjs add content of one object array into another

Tags: angularjs, json

I have two variables:

First one:

```
 studentSearchCriteria1=   {"studentList1":"key":"firstName","match":$scope.firstName,  "value":$scope.studentSearchCriteria.studentfName},],"searchUserInformationKey": [ "",],"start": 0}
```

and the second:

```
 var studentSearchCriteria1 = {"studentList2":[{"key":"lastName","match":$scope.firstName,"value":$scope.studentSearchCriteria.studentlName},],"searchUserInformationKey":["",],"start": 0}
```

I want add content of one array to another and result should be:

```
{"studentList1": [{"key":"firstName","match":$scope.firstName,"value":$scope.studentSearchCriteria.studentfName},{"key":"lastName","match":$scope.firstName,"value":$scope.studentSearchCriteria.studentlName},],"searchUserInformationKey":["",],"start": 0}
```

Comment: please guide me for this addition  of data into json object array using angularjs

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish, and You Feed Him for a Lifetime.Start fishing first, then ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript `push` method and angular copy method `angulat.copy(json)`.

```
studentSearchCriteria1.studentList1.push(angular.copy(secondJson));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy i got it